# Proof of sum convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\sqrt{n} + 1}{n^2 + n + 1}$$

This seems like a problem that could be handled by the comparison test.

So we need an $f(n) > \displaystyle \frac{2\sqrt{n} + 1}{n^2 + n + 1}$

So we need $\text{num}f(n) > 2\sqrt{n} + 1$ and $\text{denom}f(n) < n^2 + n + 1$.

So obviously, we can let $\text{denom}f(n) = n^2$ and we can try $\text{num}f(n) = 3n$

So we have $f(n) = \frac{3}{n} >  \frac{2\sqrt{n} + 1}{n^2 + n + 1}$

but this fails?

Comment: Try $\frac{3}{x^{1.5}}$

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, but you gave up too much in the numerator. Instead, observe that
$$ \frac{2\sqrt{n}+1}{n^2+n+1}\leq \frac{2\sqrt{n}+1}{n^2}\leq \frac{3\sqrt{n}}{n^2}=\frac{3}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ 
and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ converges.

Comment: How do we prove that second series converges? Is it via the $p$-test? Since $1/n^p$ and $p > 1$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the sum converges is irrelevant with the first infinite terms. So we can focus on the terms when n tends to infinity. In this sense, 
 $$ \frac{2 \sqrt{n}+1}{n^2+n+1}  \sim n^{-3/2} $$